# Highcharts- How to style the colums to have gradient colors

Tags: highcharts

I am using Highcharts5.0.7. I have a column chart, but i dont know how to style the columns of the column chart to show gradients colors like the below screenshot. I also want to show gradient colors on the guage chart.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may add the following option into colors array:

```
linearGradient: {
   x1: 0,
   y1: 0,
   x2: 1,
   y2: 0
```

}

Here you can refer an example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/A7zSf/)

Answer (score 0):

below links answers this question
http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/colors

http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/gradients-shadows-and-patterns